# Dynamic rendering of popup component vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I would like to create a VueJS app and I have a problem. I would like to be able to display some components and when I will right click on it, a popup will be displayed. The problem is that the popup will be different for every component. I saw something with the component id but I don't know if It can be answer to my problem.

Example of code :

```js
Vue.component('component', {
 template: `<button v-on:click="showPopup()">Open popup</button>`
})

Vue.component('popup1', {
template: '<div>Some complex features ... </button>'
})

Vue.component('popup2', {
template: '<div>Another complex features ... </button>'
})
```

The idea here is that the component 'component' don't really know which popup to display. It will be the function showPopup that will know the popup.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I did not try anything before I would like to know if there is exist a solution with VueJS. Actually, my app is developed in Java, but I would like to toggle it in Vue

Comment: This should be a pretty simple implementation to build, but it's hard to provide an example without any of your code. How different is the popup, completely different component, or same component with different props? 
Maybe if you provide a stripped down example of your code, it'll be easier for people to answer.

Comment: The popups will be completely different. I will try to write some code in my question

Comment: Okay, I've written a [sample app](https://codesandbox.io/s/nervous-dew-kjb4ts) as a demo, and explained it in [my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71758406/979052). Hope that helps :)

Comment: You should accept one of your answers, will help others with a similar question in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Here's a working example: 
 https://codesandbox.io/s/nervous-dew-kjb4ts

---

#### Step 1

Make a modal - see [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/nervous-dew-kjb4ts?file=/src/components/Modal.vue).

We can use slots to put dynamic content, like other components in each instance of the modal, and named slots for multiple sections. We will control visibility in the outer component / the mixin.

```
<template>
  <transition name="modal">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <slot name="header"> default header </slot>
    </div>

    <div class="modal-body">
      <slot name="body"> default body </slot>
    </div>
    <slot name="footer">
      Default Footer
      <button class="modal-default-button" @click="$emit('close')">
       Close
      </button>
    </slot>
  </transition>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "Modal",
};
</script>

<style scoped>
// See link above for full styles
</style>
```

#### Step 2

Create a mixin that all components containing a modal can extend from. Here we'll put methods for opening, closing and anything else you need. Create a data attribute to indicate modal state for use with v-if, then add two methods for opening and closing.

```
import Modal from "@/components/Modal";

export default {
  components: {
    Modal
  },
  data: () => ({
    modalState: false
  }),
  methods: {
    openModal() {
      this.modalState = true;
    },
    closeModal() {
      this.modalState = false;
    },
  },
};
```

#### Step 3

Create your components, that extend from the mixin, and use the modal component with whatever content you like.

You can trigger right-clicks using: `@mouseup.right`

```
<template>
  <div class="example-component comp1">
    <h2>Component 1</h2>
    <button @contextmenu.prevent
      @mouseup.right="openModal()"
      @click="tryRightClick()">
      Open Component 1 Modal
    </button>
    <Modal v-if="modalState" @close="closeModal()">
      <template v-slot:header> Component 1 Modal</template>
      <template v-slot:body>
        Lorem ipsum 
      </template>
    </Modal>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import modalMixin from "@/mixins/component-modal-mixin";

export default {
  mixins: [modalMixin],
};
</script>
```

#### Step 4

Finally, just import your components.

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <h3>StackOverflow Answer for Terbah Dorian</h3>
    <i>Example of separate components opening separate modals</i>
    <Component1 />
    <Component2 />
    <Component3 />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Component1 from "@/components/Component1";
import Component2 from "@/components/Component2";
import Component3 from "@/components/Component3";

export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
    Component1,
    Component2,
    Component3,
  },
};
</script>
```

Hope that helps :)
If it did, then an upvote would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can send a simple data to know which popup should be show to your client,
for example:

#### in App.vue setup() section you have this :

```
const popup = reactive({
    type: "none",
    data: "hello world"
});

const popupToggle = ref(false);

function showPopup(type, data){
    popup.type = type;
    popup.data = data;
    popupToggle.value = true;
}
    
function closePopup(){
    popup.type = "none";
    popup.data = "empty";
    popupToggle.value = false;
}
```

#### and provide your functions into your project with :

```
provide("popupFunctions", {showPopup, closePopup});
```

#### and inject provided functions in other child documents with :

```
const {showPopup, closePopup} = inject("popupFunctions");
```

now all you need is call the functions which named `showPopup` and `closePopup` to change `popup` variable which you created before in your App.vue and check the `popup` type to show the targeted component as a popup to your client

#### Something like this in <template> section in your App.vue :

```
<popup-component v-if="popupToggle">
    <popup-msgbox v-if="popup.type === 'msgBox'" :popup-data="popup.data" />
    <popup-formbox v-else-if="popup.type === 'formBox'" :popup-data="popup.data" />
    <popup-errorbox v-else-if="popup.type === 'errBox'" :popup-data="popup.data" />
</popup-component>
```

of course you should import these components and other required things in your project as you know, and i just tried to clear the solve way for you.
I hope my answer be clear to you and help you solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

https://codesandbox.io/s/laughing-shape-18dnqq?file=/src/App.vue

I made a working sample to display dynamic popovers by hovering the buttons. You can use [Slots](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html) in Vue components.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Oh, did I miss-understand what he meant by pop-ups? ‍♀️ I presumed they were modals, and never even thought about tooltip popovers...